# ssh: too many authentication failures

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, ssh-keys

I sometimes see this issue when trying to ssh to a host. Most often when going through git (since I ssh with git more often than I ssh directly).

The output from ssh looks like this:

```
Received disconnect from <server ip> port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from <server ip> port 22
```

I've also gone through an SSH proxy, and in that case the output looks like this:

```
Received disconnect from UNKNOWN port 65535:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from UNKNOWN port 65535
Killed by signal 1.
```

From the face of the error message, it looks like my account has been locked out - i.e. typically what happens if you enter your password incorrectly too many times.  But I only authenticate using ssh keys, and this had worked a few days prior.

Looking at the verbose output (using ssh -v), I don't see much more that helps, but it does tell me that it has tried to use all `IdentityFile`s configured for this host pattern in my `.ssh/config` file as well as all identities available in my ssh-agent.

I have recently added new keys to the agent due to our quarterly key rotation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the verbose output using `ssh -v` and see which keys and how many keys are being used.

For example, the output might contain the following:

```
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 7 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: .ssh/Key-2022-Q3 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxx explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: .ssh/Key-2022-03-14 RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxx explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: .ssh/Key-2023-02-13 RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxx explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Key-2023-01-20 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxx agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Key-2022-04-12 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxx agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Key-2022-12-14 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxx agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Key-2023-03-20 ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxx agent
```

In the above example, we see that ssh will attempt to use 7 keys to authenticate with the remote server.  The first 3 are specified explicitly via either an entry in your `.ssh/config` file that matches the Host pattern, or via the `-i` command line parameter.

In my case, my `.ssh/config` file contains this:

```
<global section>
IdentityFile .ssh/Key-2022-03-14

...
Host *.<domain match>
    IdentityFile .ssh/Key-2022-Q3

...
Host <exact match>
    IdentityFile .ssh/Key-2023-02-13
```

Basically, 3 identity files that match the conditions for this host:

1. Global match
2. subdomain match
3. Exact host match

ssh will attempt all three of these keys.

All these keys are also loaded into my running `ssh-agent` along with 4 additional keys.

Run `ssh-add -L` to get a list of keys that the agent will supply.  In my case it includes all 7 of the keys listed above.

The problem here is that each incorrect key that is offered and fails, counts as a failed login attempt. In this case, there will be multiple failed login attempts before we get to the correct key, and this results in the **"Too many authentication failures"** error.

To solve this, we update the `.ssh/config` file and tell ssh to explicitly only use this key.  We need to add the following two lines to the exact host match section:

```
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityAgent none
```

The first tells ssh to only use the Identity file specified in the config file, and the second says to disable the agent when using this host:

```
     IdentitiesOnly
             Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the configured authentication identity and certificate files (either the default files, or those explicitly configured in the ssh_config files or passed on the ssh(1) command-line), even if ssh-agent(1) or a PKCS11Provider or
             SecurityKeyProvider offers more identities.  The argument to this keyword must be yes or no (the default).  This option is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identities.

     IdentityAgent
             Specifies the UNIX-domain socket used to communicate with the authentication agent.

             This option overrides the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable and can be used to select a specific agent.  Setting the socket name to none disables the use of an authentication agent.  If the string "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" is specified, the location of the socket will be read
             from the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable.  Otherwise if the specified value begins with a ‘$’ character, then it will be treated as an environment variable containing the location of the socket.
```

If we attempt the `ssh` after making these changes, we see that the list of keys offered is reduced to just one:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: .ssh/Key-2023-02-13 RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxx explicit
```

It also no longer lists `agent` as the source of this key.

Authentication now succeeds on the first key, and access is granted.

Comment: You can also set those values as options, e.g. `ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes ...`.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and still can't access. Do you know if the hash that appears in the log (debug1: Will attempt key: .ssh/Key-2023-02-13 RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxx explicit in your case) should be equal to the string in the pub file? In my case, there are different but I don't know if it matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may happen when you add too many ssh-keys into your ssh-agent. Anyone who actively uses it can hit the limit eventually.

You can check it first with `ssh -v` and then just to clean up all keys with `ssh-add -D` as a quick and dirty solution.

You can also change the parameter `#MaxAuthTries 6` in **sshd_config** of the specific server